# embed png in rmarkdown table

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a dataframe in R with a number of attributes about a bunch of sequence motifs. One of the columns contains a path to a png image of the motif. I want to use rmarkdown to save the file as an html page displaying the dataframe or table with all of the attributes and have the PNG images show up. I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: assuming the dataframe is `d` and the column of png images is `d$png`, try this: ```{r echo = F, results = 'asis'}
for (i in d$png) { cat ('\n### ',i,"\n");cat('\n![',i,'](',i,')\n') }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's **always** good to start with some reproducible example:

   ```
   df <- data.frame(name = c('bicycle', 'binoculars', 'globe'))
   df$url <- paste0('http://fa2png.io/static/images/',
                    df$name, '_000000_64.png')
   ```
2. Call `pander::pandoc.image` to render image markup from the above URLs in markdown:

   ```
   library(pander)
   df$url <- sapply(df$url, pandoc.image.return)
   ```
3. Render the markdown table:

   ```
   pander(df)
   ```

---

Resulting in the following table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   name                                url                             
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
 bicycle    ![](http://fa2png.io/static/images/bicycle_000000_64.png)  

binoculars ![](http://fa2png.io/static/images/binoculars_000000_64.png)

  globe      ![](http://fa2png.io/static/images/globe_000000_64.png)   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That can be converted to HTML or whatever other format is required by e.g. `pandoc`:

```
pandoc -t html
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to run all those within R? Like save pander's result to a file and run pandoc to generate the PDF/Html. I found that pander will print the result, but not save to a file.

Comment: @user2149631 use the `Pandoc.brew` function to generate the report or try the more popular `knitr` package

Comment: @daroczig: would you have any recommendations to address the requirements for my table problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058692/table-in-bookdown-huskydown-with-several-features-citation-caption-url-png-f/60058693#60058693 ? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @daroczig can you help me on this Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756969/grouping-multiple-png-with-sub-headings-in-rmarkdown)